# Data tags not accepted in Post feed footer

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I am trying to add the following HTML under Post feed footer box. It throws error - Your HTML cannot be accepted. Tags are not nested properly A.

When I tried to encode it, it does not return error but data tags don't get computed in that case. I mean it should show POST TITLE/URL in footer instead of the text 'data:post.url'. If data tags are not allowed in settings, is there any way to include it in template?

```
 The post <a expr:href='data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a> appeared first on <a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'><data:blog.title/></a>
```